# What is to happen/what will happen

Tags: sentence-construction

> When you have someone like him in your group, you know what is to happen

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you expect that something will happen in the future, I suggest you to use *GOING TO*:

> When you have someone like him in your group, you know what is going to happen

Cambridge dictionary for [going to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/going-to)

Comment: If I talk about possibilities,then?

Comment: you can use also "goint to" if you are expecting something to happen in the future, so let me say that you can still use going to if you have a small possibility

Comment: "Both of us imagined we were seeing what was to become of Freida" - (The Bluest eyes by Tony Morrison) Isn't this sentence similar to my original question? If yes then don't they express the same meaning???

Comment: I mean they are very different... This one is in the past while the other is in the future!!!

Comment: So, in the past tense it's okay to use but not in the future tense. Is this it? Sorry I don't mean to bother you, I just want to be clear on this, sorry for the trouble...

Comment: GOING TO is used only with the FUTURE (see link of the cambridge dictionary in my response) while you can't use it in the past. Don't worry! you're welcome!

Comment: Thank you for your time..

Comment: you are welcome!!